# Is it possible to make a web page apart of Facebook only visible to fans of a Facebook fan page?

Tags: html, facebook

I need this function because I want to let the fans of a page print out some shopping coupons, and as far as I know it isn't possible to print out the content of a Facebook Page tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, Facebook pages run in an iFrame, so it's easy to see if a user is seeing it from an iframe that is hosted at facebook or not

You can also see if the user is authenticated through FB Javascript API and redirect to the proper page.

That what mainly we do.

---

So you want to run a website far way from Facebook ... well, just use **their Javascript SDK** to make the user login into your "*Fan page*" and when he's login you redirect to the only-fan-page.

**You will need to create a Facebook App** to get a API Key and Secret in order to use the SDK.

Without that, you will never know if the user is a FB user or not.

Start your reading here:

> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Sorry maybe I don't get it right but I want to create a Fan Gate apart of Facebook. What code should I use for it?